# Basic Validation rule which has baffled me

Tags: validation, picklist

Yet again this has simple validation has me baffled

Aim – If mailing country = Canada, then Canada_Email_Consent__c  needs to be captured, if mailing country not equal to  Canada  then Canada_Email_Consent__c  is not applicable

> Field Label : Canada Email Consent
>
> Data type : Picklist
>
> Values : Yes/No

Okay First of all I have created the following validation;

Validation rule : Mailing Country

Error Formula:

```
ISBLANK(MailingCountry)
```

Second validation i have is

Rule name : Testing_Canada_Email_Consent

Error Formula:

```
AND( 
Upper(MailingCountry) = 'CANADA', 
ISBLANK(TEXT(Canada_Email_Consent__c)) 
)
```

Currently with the rules set up in place, if you type any other country Canada_Email_Consent__c is populated to yes. if mailing country = canada then Canada_Email_Consent__c is required

looking forward to your help

Comment: Is MailingCountry also a picklist?

Comment: @ Jagular - I cant describe it, but when you type a characther it narrows down your search. For eg if i type in U into the mailing country, i get the values, USA,UK, Uganda etc

Comment: @user8746 can you paste what you see in your debug log, it should say the validation name and that the rule fails and why it failed

Comment: @Rao- the rule is not failing. Currently, if the mailing country is not equal to Canada its populating Canada_Email_Consent__c with YES. I want it to say that if mailing country is not Canada, then Canada_Email_Consent__c should not be applicable. if mailing country is Canada, then they should have the choice from "Yes or No" from the field Canada Email Consent

Comment: These are validation rules.  Is there also a workflow rule affecting the field?

Comment: @jagular - there is no workflow in relation to these fields

Comment: if i am getting it right, you want to throw an error message that the picklist Canada_Email_Consent__c cannot be edited if mailing country is canada and the rest should have the yes/ no option right?

Comment: Canada_email_consent should only be populated if mailing country = Canada , if mailing country is anything else then Canada_email_consent shouldn't apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the or condition...
OR(AND( 
Upper(MailingCountry) <> 'CANADA', 
NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Canada_Email_Consent__c))),
AND( 
Upper(MailingCountry) = 'CANADA', 
ISBLANK(TEXT(Canada_Email_Consent__c)) 
)

Comment: hi JJbennett530 thank you for providing a answer, however when i populate mailing country with UK for eg the field "Canada Email Consent" is being populated to yes, when in fact the field shouldnt be populated at all.

Comment: A validation rule checks to see if the fields have the correct content, a workflow rule can be set up to populate the field or you could have a dependant picklist or a formula field, that sets the data. You might also check to see if there is a default value for that picklist field.

Comment: jjbennett530 the validation is -- OR(AND( Upper(MailingCountry) <> 'CANADA', NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Canada_Email_Consent__c)))), AND( Upper(MailingCountry) = 'CANADA', ISBLANK(TEXT(Canada_Email_Consent__c))) ) and i also had a workflow updating the field whoopsie. Thank you for your assistance